Garbage collector in for loop
I was having leak problems with julia, so I decided to test some basic features and I realized that garbage collector is not activated after each iteration of a for loop. This can be seen by this file:
File test1.jl
function main(size)
    # Measure memory allocated by creating the array
    sleep(10)
    println("Creating 2 matrix of size: $size")
    A = rand(Float64, (size, size))
    B = rand(Float64, (size, size))
    sleep(10)
    println("multiplying A=A*B")
    for i in 1:10
        A = A*B
        #GC.gc()
        sleep(5)
    end
    println("Done")
    sleep(10)
end

if length(ARGS) == 1
    size = parse(Int, ARGS[1])
    main(size)
else
    println("Usage: julia test1.jl <size>")
end

Togheter with the scripts:
run.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the size argument is provided
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: ./run.sh <size>"
    exit 1
fi

SIZE=$1

# Start the Julia program and capture its PID
julia test1.jl $SIZE &
JULIA_PID=$!
echo "Julia PID: $JULIA_PID"

# Pass the PID to another script and run it in a new terminal
konsole -e bash -c "./monitor_script.sh $JULIA_PID; exec bash"

and monitor_script.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the PID from the argument
JULIA_PID=$1
echo "Monitoring Julia process with PID: $JULIA_PID"

# Monitor the process (example: using top)
top -p $JULIA_PID

You can notice that if the line GC.gc() is commented in the file test1.jl, the ram is going to increase at each iteration.
Is there a way to change this behavior of the garbage collector? or do I have to force it at each loop?

You don't want GC to run after each loop. GC is expensive and so it's only run once you've allocated enough to make running the GC worthwhile.

I'm working with very big matrices, either this or I'm going to run out of ram, for this reason I'm asking for alternatives or advices

for big matrices, it should still run GC as needed. Every allocation has a check for whether GC should be run so each loop iteration will check whether it wants to run GC.
